# iOS: RTMP client library to stream from iOS client to Red5 media server gives "Connection reset by peer" error after few streams

Tags: ios, audio, rtmp, red5

I am using the iOS RTMP client library used here https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x to stream audio from the iOS device to the server.

I establish a socket connection and then allow the user to record a sentence and stream each phrase to the server using the connection. The user can repeat the process and each sentence is sent as a different stream. This works for about 5 minutes and then I start getting the "connection reset by peer" error from the server.

Any ideas on why this could be happening? Or how to resolve it?

Comment: You connection may be getting dropped to its non-responsiveness to the server pings / control messages.